# Pattern matching in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am doing pattern match for some names below:

```
ABCD123_HH1
ABCD123_HH1_K
```

Now, my code to grep above names is below:

```
($name, $kind) = $dirname =~ /ABCD(\d+)\w*_([\w\d]+)/;
```

Now, problem I am facing is that I get both the patterns that is `ABCD123_HH1`, `ABCD123_HH1_K` in `$dirname`. However, my variable `$kind` doesn't take this `ABCD123_HH1_K`. It does take `ABCD123_HH1` pattern.

Appreciate your time. Could you please tell me what can be done to get pattern with `_k`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the `_K` part to the end of your regex and make it optional with `?`:

```
/ABCD(\d+)_([\w\d]+(_K)?)/
```

I also erased the `\w*`, which is useless and keeps you from correctly getting the `HH1_K`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `(_K)?` rather than `(_K)*` to avoid matching multiple instances of `_K` (depending a bit on what the OP wants, I guess)?

Comment: @PhilipKendall As far as I understand his strings either have "_K" or don't, so I think it doesn't change anything. Your solution is better anyway though so I'll edit :)

Comment: thank you alestanis and philip. So, I should add my code as below:($name, $kind) = $dirname =~ /ABCD(\d+)\w*_([\w\d]+)(_K)/; Let me try and btw I am " her" :)

Comment: @user1985039 Don't forget the `?` after the `_K` or you won't match `ABCD123_HH1` !

Comment: @user1985039 I just tested the regex and realized it doesn't work in the `ABCD123_HH1_K` case because you have an extra `\w*` that gets it wrong. I corrected the regex in my answer. Take a look at it!

Answer (score 1):

You should check for zero or more occurrences of `_K`.

> `*` in Perl's regexp means zero or more times
>
> `+` means atleast one or more times.

Hence in your regexp, append `(_K)*`.

Finally, your regexp should be this:

```
/ABCD(\d+)\w*_([\w\d]+(_K)*)/
```

Comment: Hi, It is still not taking... I am printing $kind and it is not showing patterns with _K variable. :(

Comment: I want $kind to print the whole thing like "HH1_K" and $name as "ABCD123"

Answer (score 0):

`\w` includes letters, numbers as well as underscores.

So you can use something as simple as this:
`/ABCD\w+/`

Comment: No, it pulled out the one which was even printing... I 'll try thank you :)